# Do archived documents in Salesforce CRM content count against storage limitations?

Tags: limits, content

I am loking for info if archived Content counts against storage limitations in Salesforce.
Could it be possible that only benefit of archiving Content is having them not displayed in search results and in Library content?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Short Answer

Yes it does count!

### How did I find out?

I can't find any specific information regarding the storage, but given that the limits are in place to control a multi-tenant system, and that you can retrieve archived content ([as per the docs](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=content_delete.htm&language=en_US)) it would be reasonable to expect that it does count. I just performed a simple test in one of my developer orgs, and uploaded an file to content which was ~1MB, this showed up in the storage usage screen as expected:

[image: Storage after loading content]

I then archived this content (note the icon):

[image: Archived content]

... but as you can see, it still counts towards my usage:

[image: Archived content still counts!]

After deleting the content I'm back to square one (Pawel's comment prompted some more testing here, there's definitely a delay, but archived content does seem to count, whereas content in the recycle bin does not)"

[image]

Comment: Are you sure, that you have to empty recycle bin? There is an info, that "Nothing that is deleted counts against storage": http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_monitorresources.htm

Comment: I did check the storage before and after emptying the recycle bin... either there's a different rule for content or the storage page takes a little while to update.

Comment: I've juest received answer from Salesforce.com support and you are right: archived content does count against storage limitations.

Comment: Content in Recycle Bin also counts against limitations. Tested it, and it is also confirmed by Salesforce support. Thanks!

Comment: That's weird, my storage usage went down when I left it in the recycle bin! I wonder if it doesn't count visibly but does in the background or something weird.

Comment: I find this very very strange, why then would someone archive content in the first place? Or does it just take less space then the original files? (like some sort of compression)

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw in my two cents.

We had some clients that needed to upload and store very large files in Salesforce so we developed an excellent Salesforce storage App that gives you unlimited file size upload and unlimited storage capacity at a great price. It's used by some great companies, like VMware.

You can check it out here:
http://www.clouddrop.io

For Application visit:
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IzEDEA0